# Attempting to read file from blob storage in Azure function yields "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to read a json config file from Azure blob storage from within an Azure function.  This works fine when running in locally in VS2019 but when running Azure it yields a  "The system cannot find the file specified" error.  Access to the container is via key so it doesn't seem like user vs. msi context but I could be wrong.  Code looks like:

```
log.LogInformation($"Got blockBlobReference, starting streamreader");
try
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            blockBlobReference.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"ParseConfigurationBlob:  DownloadToStreamAsync failed: {ex.Message} ");
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProvisioningConfiguration>(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError($"ParseConfigurationBlob:  Unable to read JSONBlobConfigurationFile - {ex.Message} ");
}
```

Curiously the catch never fires, instead I get:

```
2020-04-23T14:00:00.286 [Information] Got blockBlobReference, starting streamreader
2020-04-23T14:00:00.594 [Error] ProvisionBuilder:  The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Please see this: https://forums.asp.net/t/2120052.aspx?JsonConvert+Deserialize+throwing+exception+in+Asp+Net+Core. Looks like same problem as you're facing.

Comment: Thanks.  Curious that it works in one context but not the other

Comment: Quite possible that you have proper files installed on your computer that may be missing in Azure Function.

Comment: Same file, different access method.  If I include the file as part of the publish set it works fine.  The same file uploaded to blob works fine when executed locally but not when read back from the blob.

Comment: Is there any way to get more details about the error? May be dump full stack trace. I don't think it has anything to do with reading blob.

Comment: Agree, it's about the conversion.  Will see what I can dump when running in Azure context

Comment: So the most bizarre thing...  My functions are published to two completely separate tenants - different msi, keyvault, cloud storage, etc.  One tenant work fine, the other fails with the file not found error.  I can't fathom how/why there's any interaction but that's the appearance.